# Silent Dropbox removal

Tags: windows, windows-7, uninstallation, windows-shell, silent

I use the following script in [Npackd](http://code.google.com/p/windows-package-manager/) to uninstall Dropbox. It works on XP and Vista, but fails on Windows 7/64. Instead of showing the taskbar (the one that is normally at the bottom of the screen) it shows a Windows Explorer window with the content of C:/. This is not Dropbox related as removing other packages with DLL based shell extensions also shows the same effect.

```
Uninstall.exe /S _?=%CD%
taskkill /f /fi "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe"
del DropboxExt.13.dll
del DropboxExt64.13.dll
rem start explorer from the root directory so it does not lock this one
start "" /D\ explorer.exe
```

What is wrong with the script? How can it be modified to work correctly on Windows 7 too?

Thanks

EDIT: I am really tired of this problem. The following batch file works either started as a normal user or "As Administrator":

```
taskkill /f /fi "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe"
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1
pushd \
rem runas /trustlevel:0x20000 
start "" /D\ explorer.exe
popd
```

Here is the code that starts the .bat from my program (path="Uninstall.bat", only 2 new environment variables are defined):

```
QDir d = this->getDirectory();
QProcess p(0);
p.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
QStringList params;
p.setWorkingDirectory(d.absolutePath());
QString exe = d.absolutePath() + "\\" + path;
for (int i = 0; i < env.count(); i += 2) {
    p.processEnvironment().insert(env.at(i), env.at(i + 1));
}
p.start(exe, params);
```

The corresponding code in Qt/qprocess_win.cpp:

```
DWORD dwCreationFlags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW;
dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
STARTUPINFOW startupInfo = { sizeof( STARTUPINFO ), 0, 0, 0,
                             (ulong)CW_USEDEFAULT, (ulong)CW_USEDEFAULT,
                             (ulong)CW_USEDEFAULT, (ulong)CW_USEDEFAULT,
                             0, 0, 0,
                             STARTF_USESTDHANDLES,
                             0, 0, 0,
                             stdinChannel.pipe[0], stdoutChannel.pipe[1], stderrChannel.pipe[1]
};
success = CreateProcess(0, (wchar_t*)args.utf16(),
                        0, 0, TRUE, dwCreationFlags,
                        environment.isEmpty() ? 0 : envlist.data(),
                        workingDirectory.isEmpty() ? 0 : (wchar_t*)QDir::toNativeSeparators(workingDirectory).utf16(),
                        &startupInfo, pid);
```

Why does the Explorer think there is already a taskbar?

EDIT2: I know what is wrong now. After the Explorer is killed a new is automatically started by an svchost.exe process with the following parameters: /factory,{682159d9-c321-47ca-b3f1-30e36b2ec8b9}. The GUID is for DesktopExplorerFactory. This is probably a crash-protection for a COM service. My calls to explorer.exe do not start a new Explorer as there is already one. After a minute or two this process will be automatically closed if no windows are opened. So I think Ben Voigt is right and "There's really no good way to unload the shell completely without logging off all users."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with the script is quite simple: The shell is loaded into many **many** applications besides just Windows Explorer.  Every application that uses the common open/save file dialogs hosts the shell.

To address your immediate question of how to control the working directory of Windows Explorer without passing arguments that open a window, just set the working directory:

```
pushd C:\
start explorer.exe
popd
```

But this still will not let you reliably delete the extension.  There's really no good way to unload the shell completely without logging off all users.

EDIT: Is your script running at the same integrity level as the original explorer.exe you killed?  Same elevation level?  The shell runs with medium (normal) integrity level and unelevated token, you need to match this.

Comment: pushd/popd do not help unfortunately

Comment: I also already know how to control the working directory of the Windows Explorer: see the "/D\" in my question. My question is only about Windows 7.

Comment: you were right about "shell being loaded into many applications". As example Filezilla client loads SHELL32.DLL which loads DropboxExt.14.dll. Nonetheless it is important to be able to restart explorer.exe as it is the most common case and an average user does not know how to restart it.

Comment: I didn't know there is something like integrity level (they are also called trust levels sometimes). runas /trustlevel:0x20000 does not help. The started Explorer window also has the middle integrity level.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, your command "start "" /d\ explorer.exe" seems to work fine for me even on win7, it restarts the taskbar & desktop if it's been killed.

However, you don't really need "start". You can just call "explorer.exe" from a batch file, it won't block. Not sure if this makes a difference but it's worth a try.

By the way, if it doesn't work... what happens on the affected computer if you bring up the task manager with ctrl+shift+esc and do a File->Run "explorer"? Does that start the taskbar or will it, again, produce an explorer window? If this produces the expected results there may be something wrong with the batch file or its environment. Such as not being run as the currently logged on user, etc.

Explorer should start the taskbar if there are no other instances of its own process around. The fact that the shell itself may be loaded into other processes does not matter... you can kill all instances of explorer, have a "file open" dialog up in Excel, and still restart the taskbar by running explorer.exe from the task manager.

Comment: My point about the shell being loaded in other processes really has nothing to do with restarting explorer, but concerns deletion of the shell extension, which a File Open dialog in some other application will prevent.

Comment: Makes sense. What about the rest of the stuff?

Comment: I can't reproduce his behavior either, but I'm guessing that his uninstall script is running with an administrator token (or else it couldn't delete files from the Program Files area) and not the logged-in user.  Or maybe the explorer process being killed isn't quite dead yet, when the new one goes deciding whether it's going to be a desktop/taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the following line

```
start "" /D\ explorer.exe
```

with this one

```
start "" /D\ %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe
```

This should run explorer without parameters.

The thing is that running explorer without full path runs it with parameters you specified:

```
/factory,{682159d9-c321-47ca-b3f1-30e36b2ec8b9}
```

but I have no clue why this happens.